# How can I delete an editable div by clicking on it and then pressing the Delete key on the keyboard with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a div with the attribute contenteditable = true. I can activate the div content editing by double clicking the div, this is because my div is draggable, so I use the dooble click event to activate the div edition. The fact is that I want to eliminate the complete div by clicking on it and then pressing the Delete key on the keyboard. How can I do that? How can I make it so that when I write something on the div and press the delete key, the entire div will not be deleted? I only want to delete the div when the div edition is not activated, just click on the div and then hit the delete key and voila, it is deleted.

This is my HTML Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.draggable').draggable({
    containment: "parent"
  });

  $(".draggable").resizable();

  $('#MyFirstDiv').click(function() {
    //HERE I WANT TO PUT THE CODE TO DELETE THE DIV.
  });

  $("#myContainer").on("dblclick", "#MyFirstDiv", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".draggable").draggable('disable');

    this.querySelector(":scope > :first-child").focus();

  });

  $("#myContainer").on("blur", "#MyFirstDiv", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".draggable").draggable('enable');
  });

});
```

```css
#myContainer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}

#DraggableDiv {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My Delete Div</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="myContainer">
    <div id="MyFirstDiv">
      <div class="draggable" contenteditable="true" id="DraggableDiv">
        THIS IS MY TEXT INSIDE THE DIV
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: To be clear: do you want: "click on div, then press delete" or "click on div and press on delete _while_ clicking div"?

Comment: I don't want delete while clicking the div, I just want to click on div first and then press the delete key from de keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to to capture the keydown on the delete key.

```
$('#MyFirstDiv').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); 
});
$('#MyFirstDiv').keydown(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(e.keyCode == 46) {
        this.remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: it's not working. I press the delete key but nothing is deleted.

Comment: Are you clicking the div first? It needs to be brought into focus.

Comment: yes, I did click the div first and then I press the delete key but nothing happens

Comment: Any console errors? Can you link me to live version I could check it out

Comment: I have double checked the code using your code above, it definitely deletes when the box is selected and delete is pressed. If the JS is from an external source file try refreshing cache.   

https://output.jsbin.com/xurojeraba <- working example with your code

Comment: It didn't work, I check the example you posted but it 's not working,

Answer (score 0):

You could first just make a variable: `divClicked`, I store the clicked state of the div

```
var divClicked = false;
```

Then in your event listener, update `divClicked` (it'll be a toggled button):

```
$("#MyFirstDiv").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    divClicked = !divClicked;
}
```

Finally, add a delete key event listener like so:

```
$("#MyFirstDiv").keydown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.keyCode == 46) {
        if (divClicked) {
            $(this).remove();
        } else {
            alert("Click the div first then press Delete to remove it");
        }
    }
})
```

Full code:

```
var divClicked = false;

$("#MyFirstDiv").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    divClicked = !divClicked;
}

$("#MyFirstDiv").keydown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.keyCode == 46) {
        if (divClicked) {
            $(this).remove();
        } else {
            alert("Click the div first then press Delete to remove it");
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: it doesn't work. The div doesn't delete when I press delete key. Console did not display any error.

Comment: You're meant to click the div first like you said in your question.

Comment: Yes, click on div first and then press delete key. Only click on the div like you're selecting the element and then press delete key.

Comment: @JackBashford consider if OP has more than 1 of these types of draggable elements. May consider using `.data()` to store if the draggable has been selected or not versus a variable.

Answer (score 0):

It is not advisable to use <kbd>Delete</kbd> while the content is being edited. You will want to ensure that the user can click the `<div>` element itself without editing the content.

Since the `<div>` is draggable, I would advise using a handle since the `click` event and `keypress` events may get capture for content editing and not for your script.

```js
$(function() {
  function disDrag(part) {
    var drag = part.closest(".draggable");
    drag.draggable("disable");
    $(".drag-content", drag).removeAttr("contenteditable").blur();
    part.toggleClass("ui-icon-locked ui-icon-unlocked");
  }

  function enDrag(part) {
    var drag = part.closest(".draggable");
    drag.draggable("enable");
    $(".drag-content", drag).attr("contenteditable", true).focus();
    part.toggleClass("ui-icon-locked ui-icon-unlocked");
  }

  function delDrag(part) {
    var drag = part.closest(".draggable");
    var res = confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete this item?");
    if (res) {
      drag.remove();
    }
  }

  $('.draggable')
    .draggable({
      containment: "parent",
      handle: ".ui-drag-handle",
      start: function() {
        $(".ui-drag-handle", this).data("selectable", false);
      },
      stop: function() {
        $(".ui-drag-handle", this).data("selectable", true);
      }
    })
    .resizable();

  $(".ui-drag-handle")
    .data("selectable", true)
    .click(function(e) {
      var drag = $(this).closest(".draggable");
      if ($(this).data("selectable")) {
        drag.toggleClass("drag-selected");
      }
    });

  $(".btn").click(function(e) {
    switch (true) {
      case $(this).hasClass("ui-icon-unlocked"):
        disDrag($(this));
        break;
      case $(this).hasClass("ui-icon-locked"):
        enDrag($(this));
        break;
      case $(this).hasClass("ui-icon-close"):
        delDrag($(this));
        break;
    }
  });

  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 46 && $(".drag-selected").length) {
      delDrag($(".drag-selected"));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#myContainer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}

.draggable {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.draggable.drag-selected {
  border: 1px solid #0f0;
}

.center {
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.ui-icon.btn {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 1px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="myContainer">
  <div class="draggable ui-widget" id="DraggableDiv">
    <div class="ui-widget-header">
      <span class="right ui-icon ui-icon-close btn" title="Delete the item."></span>
      <span class="right ui-icon ui-icon-unlocked btn" title="Lock and disable Drag"></span>
      <div class="ui-drag-handle" style="width: calc(100% - 42px);">
        <span class="center ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-horizontal"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="drag-content" contenteditable="true">
      THIS IS MY TEXT INSIDE THE DIV
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see that this is draggable, resizable, and editable. The user can disable drag by clicking the lock icon. If the select the div and click Delete (or key code 46), or they click the close icon, they will be prompted to confirm that they want to delete the item. Once they confirm that Yes they want to, the item is removed.

Since the delete could be triggered by two different ways, I created a delete function.

In regards to structure, you may not be able to get away with such simple HTML structures when dealing with more complex UI interactions. This one `<div>` element had all sorts of interactions tied to the `click` event. The user clicks to edit, select, drag... It is better to make more specific targets for some of these events so that you can better script your events.

You could save yourself a lot of time by using Dialog Widget: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

## Test

- Click on the text to select.
- Press D to delete. *[sadly delete key didn't work on stack overflow. Simply change the key code in the if statement to change the key from D to DELETE]*

## Explanation

There are two functions that help solve this problem.
**Select**: Selected the div clicked.
**EventListener:**Listens for the keypress and deletes the selected div.

#### Select function

1. Global variable selected stores the information on the div selected.
2. In select function we are fetching the id name of the div clicked by using **currentTarget.id** from the event object 'e'.
3. If statements inside the select function select and deselect the div.

#### EventListener

1. Uses event object from the keypress listener to fetch the key pressed.
2. **e.keyCode** gives the key. **e.which** is a fallback. *[for ie users]*
3. If they keyCode is 100 (D key), then use the selected variable to get the selected div and change its css display to 'none'.

> Additionally there is a else statement, where u can add js to when nothing is selected and the key is pressed.
> Also the css for class selected is for feedback of when the div is selected.

#### Here is the code snippet:

```js
let selected;

const select = e => {
    //If already selected, this will deselect the div
    if(selected == e.currentTarget.id) {
      document.getElementById(selected).classList.remove('selected'); //some CSS
      selected = null;
    } else {
       //select this div
      selected = e.currentTarget.id;
      document.getElementById(selected).classList.add('selected'); //some CSS
    }
}

window.addEventListener('keypress', e => {
  //Get key pressed
  let key = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if(selected != undefined) {
      if(key == 100) {//If D is pressed
        let target = document.getElementById(selected); //get the div
        target.style.display = 'none'; //hide div
        console.log('deleted: ' + selected);
      }
  } else {
    //Runs if nothing is selected. Do as you please here.
  }
})
```

```css
.selected {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

#DraggableDiv {
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My Delete Div</title>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="myContainer">
    <div id="MyFirstDiv">
      <div id="DraggableDiv" onclick="select(event)">
        Click me and press D
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```